# Branching a meta layer according to Yocto branches

Tags: git, embedded-linux, yocto

I have a personalized Yocto layer that is a git repository which presently only has `master` branch on it.

The development is based on the `krogoth` branch for Yocto.

Within the layer are many recipes which are *backported* from master or higher branches.

I am now upgrading from `krogoth` to `rocko` and wish to branch out on the meta layer where I wish to avoid overlapping *backported* recipes during new image builds.

Is there a workflow or tips in how to maintain a Yocto meta layer for different releases like `rocko`, `morty` etc. or should I remain on the `master` branch and continue development?

Comment: Move to rocko, and branch out master to 'rocko', move to sumo and branch it out to 'sumo'...

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk yes but I might have conflicting backport recipes

Comment: well, fix them then.

Answer (score 2):

A route we've occasionally adopted is to maintain a `meta-our-thing-backports` extra layer to go with our primary `meta-our-thing`.  In it we would have various recipes, appends, alternate patches, etc.  I cannot speak for how sustainable that model is, however, depending on how many versions you have to track.